# SSIS Buffer allocation failed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, out-of-memory

I have a parent package in SSIS that has for each loop container that executes 2 child packages in a sequential manner. The connection values are passed to the child packages as parameters. The child packages dynamically connect to a flat-file source and a derived column is being used to replace the "\N" values with NULL and it is finally loaded in the SQL server destination. The total size of the flat file source is 3GB. The for-each loop executes in the first iteration, but it is failing in the second iteration. I am getting an error message of buffer allocation failed.

**Error message**
The system reports an 85 percent memory load. There are 32767590400 bytes of physical memory with 4636983296 bytes free. There are 4294836224 bytes of virtual memory with 362987520 bytes free. The paging file has 43437899776 bytes with 13638811648 bytes free.

The Data Flow task failed to create a buffer to call PrimeOutput for output "Flat File Source" (23) on component "Flat File Source Output" (27). This error usually occurs due to an out-of-memory condition.

Memory pressure was alleviated, buffer manager is not throttling allocations anymore
(in the buffer tuning log)

I have changed the default buffer size from 10 MB to 50 MB and default buffer max rows from 10000 to 50000. also changed the rows per batch to 10000 for files larger than 100MB.

still, I am facing the same issue. can anyone help me resolve this issue?

thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest setting the *AutoAdjustBufferSize* to *True*.
Then you need to calculate the max size of the row of the table.
You can use this SQL where you replace your table and a schema in the quotes:

```
SELECT
    SUM (max_length)  [row_length]
    ,104857600.0/SUM (max_length) [Max_100MB_Buffer_Rows]
    ,2147483647.0/SUM (max_length) [Max_2GB_Buffer_Rows]
FROM  sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id=c.object_id
JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id=s.schema_id
WHERE t.name = '{my_table_name}' AND s.name = '{my_schema_name}'
```

Then depending on which version your packages are (2015 or 2017) you either use 100MB buffer (2015) or 2GB buffer (2017).
To be on the safe side use 100MB buffer.
Basically, you need to set a good Max num rows (not too high) depending on how wide your data is.